# jQuery onClick for an Already Modified Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have something that lets the user click the `<li>` which then toggles a div below it. Inside that div is a button to "Add to Short List". When clicked, it changes a background of the `li` item, as well as changes the button text to "Remove from Short List". When the button is pressed again, it needs to do the opposite of adding, it must change the `li` class back to it's original state and change the button text back.

I am having trouble getting it to work. I know that once I change the class name I'm unable to access the new class via an `onClick`.

In addition, when the button is clicked, if it's "adding" AJAX will be occurring (implemented later on) and when it's clicked to "remove" AJAX will occur to remove the corresponding thing.

`JavaScript`

```
var incSL

$('.complete, .incomplete').click(function() {

    $('.classInfo').slideUp();

    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).next().show('slow');

        incSL = this;

        // ADD
        $(".shortAdd").on('click','.button', function(){

            $(this).text('Remove from Short List');

            $(this).parent().attr("class", "shortRemove");

            $(incSL).attr("class", "incompleteSL");

        });

        // REMOVE
        $(".shortRemove .button").click(function(){

            $(this).text('Add to Short List');

            $(this).parent().attr("class", "shortAdd");

            $(incSL).attr("class", "incomplete");

        });

    }


 });
```

`HTML`

```
<li class="incomplete">ITCS 3688 Computers & Society</li>
    <div class="classInfo">
        <div class="shortAdd">
            <div class="button">Add to Short List</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`CSS`

```
.incomplete {
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -moz-opacity: 0.65;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.65;
    opacity: 0.65;
}

.incompleteSL {/* Short Listed */
    background: url('../images/short.png') right center no-repeat;
    color: #00703c;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Thanks for any help one can provide! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'ELEMENT_CLASS_OR_ID', function () {});
```

You can find something about **live events** in jquery documentation. :)